# sending managed metadata properties of file via workflow

Tags: designer-workflow, managed-metadata, flow

When you send an email via a workflow with managed metadata items they look like TERM1|ifdijfigjdiojgikdjfgidjgildjlgk.

I have tried with the new Microsoft flow and it does exactly the same (before I tried with SharePoint designer workflows).

Is there a way to clean up the code portion in order to show just the Term either in SPD Workflow or Flow? By chance is it exactly the same process? (additional 2 columns with copy=paste and removal of the extra letters with a formula?)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in MS Flow you can use `Managed Metadata Columns Label` something like this

[image]

and then you'll get only text

Answer (score 0):

When you go to use the field in flow, there should be several entries, including:

- MyMetaField Label
- MyMetaField Path
- MyMetaField Value
- MyMetaField TermGuid

The value field is as you described, but the label field should be just the content the user sees, such as "TERM1" in your example.

Edit: To handle a multi-select managed metadata field, add the following steps prior to the email:

```
Data Operations - Select:
From: MyMetaField
Map: MyMetaField Label
```

(the map property will need to be switched to "text" mode, via the button to the right. It should only display a single textbox, not a table with two columns).

The above will generate an array with one column that has the label values. then, add the following action:

```
Data Operations - Join:
From: Select Output
Join With: ;
```

The above will generate a semi-colon separated list of the labels. Of course, feel free to replace the ; with whatever.

In the email, use the output from the join operation.

Comment: I have done Label now, since it was multiple items in the same field it sent an email for each item...

Comment: I edited the answer to include steps for a multi-select managed meatadata field

Comment: when you say prior to the email you mean in the body?

Comment: In flow, the "send email" step is an action. The two actions I outlined would go prior to the email action, so that you can use the output of those steps in the email.

Comment: If I add an action, it asks me if it is a condition or else, what is it?

Comment: if you hover on the line that precedes the email action, a plus sign should appear. click it. It should present a dialog with many choices. type in "select", and look for the one labeled "data operations - select". though, adding actions to a flow is pretty basic. If you're not sure how to do this, then check out the docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/multi-step-logic-flow

Comment: I have done what you wrote and the WF failed. My actions are uploaded in the original message

Comment: Nothing should be in the for loop, the for loop can be removed. The map operation should have just the label, not the brackets, semi-colon, or other fields.

Comment: Where do you see the loop? as soon as I select the Operations - select I get automatically the 'apply to each - country'. Sorry but this is so much less intuitive from the old SPD workflows, which simply added comma separated elements.

Comment: Your screen shot has the "apply to each". That's what i'm referring to. You should be able to add the "select" step right after the trigger (when a file is created) and before the "apply to each". Likewise, the join should go right after the select, and the mail should be moved to be be outside of the apply to each.

Comment: as said earlier, as soon as I select the mapping it creates the Apply to each automatically. I cannot drag the actions 'out' of the box

Comment: weird. When I add the multi-select label item to the map property of the select action, no "apply to each" is added.

Comment: is your field multiple choice?

Comment: It's a multi-select managed metadata. If I add the metadata field directly to the email, it adds the "apply to each", but not when I add the field to the select action.

Comment: Wait, just tried it again. It adds the "apply to each" if I add the field to the Map first. Try adding the metadata field to the "from" first, and then add the metadata label to the "map" field.

Comment: ok, i managed to do it, in the email i placed output, it is still giving me the code. In the mapping i put Value:label as in the image, but I still get in the body things I do not want such as {"Country1|code":"Country1"} and the following countries written in the same way. Apparently the mapping does not work

Comment: Did you remove everything from the "map" field except for the label? It should not have brackets { } or anything else.

Comment: You told me to put the country VALUE : country LABEL. I have left just label and this is what it appears in the email {"":"Madagascar"};{"":"Netherlands"};{"":"Oman"}. Still not an exceptional results, I do not need the brackets and the quotes

Comment: There should be only one field in the "map" text box. If you mutli-select field is named "country", there should be a field that shows up with the name "country label". Add that. Nothing else. No brackets, no colon, no "value" field, no spaces, etc. Delete everything out of the "map" textbox, and then find the "country label", and click on it once to add it to the map textbox.